# How to enable 'Send User Package Usage Info', after installation?

Tags: system-installation, popcon

When I originally installed Ubuntu (first time using Linux), I chose to not participate in sending info about Package usage (ti was an install-time option)... I was in pure experimental mode and felt that any info I sent would be rather meaningless.

I've now got a good sense of what I want/need, and I'd like to know how to enable this option..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to **System → Administration → Software sources** sources, tab **Statistics** and check **Submit statistical information**.

[image]

Comment: Note: In Ubuntu 10.10 you need to open the Software Centre (in the Applications menu) and go to Edit->Software Sources